# How to do Multiple different jQuery paragraphs with replaceWith

Tags: jquery

I am attempting to do something similar to a click-through slideshow with just text. It's not getting through the second replaceWith. Here's what I have so far:

```
<p class="one">Number One</p>

<script>
$( "p.one" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).replaceWith( "<p class='two'>Number Two</p>");
});
</script>    

<script>
$( "p.two" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).replaceWith( "<p class='three'>Number Three</p>");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to delegate the `p.two` event since it was only created after DOM was loaded.

```
$( "body" ).on('click', 'p.two', function() {
  $( this ).replaceWith( "<p class='three'>Number Three</p>");
});
```

Here is a working example on jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/m7k453bv/

--

Reference according to jQuery:

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
>   parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a
>   selector, whether those descendants exist now or ***are added in the
>   future***.

https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: Glad to hear that @DanielS :) please mark my answer as accepted if there are no further issues. And welcome to SO, enjoy your stay.

Answer (score -1):

Keep everything in a document.ready function:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('click', "p.one", function() {
      $( this ).replaceWith( "<p class='two'>Number Two</p>");
    });

    $( document ).on('click', "p.two", function() {
      $( this ).replaceWith( "<p class='three'>Number Three</p>");
    });
});
</script>
```